# Signature of $S^2 \times D^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Every closed connected oriented $4$-manifold has a [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_%28topology%29), defined via a cohomological intersection form. In Turaev's book *Quantum Invariants of Knots and 3-Manifolds* the definition of a certain invariant of $3$-manifolds in chapter II uses the signature of a $4$-manifold which is not closed (actually it arises from attaching $2$-handles to a $4$-ball), which is defined using a homological intersection form.

Q1) How is this homological intersection form defined?

Q2) Why is the signature of $S^2 \times D^2$ zero? (Actually I don't know if this is true, but this seems to be used in a calculation in Turaev's book.)

Comment: That's not a closed 4- manifold!

Comment: Closed ordinarily means empty boundary in this context.

Comment: I've replaced "closed" by "connected" :)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, What have you tried? I mean, how did you get this answer?

Comment: Martin, the standard definition of signature (I admit I'm rusty) is for compact, oriented $4k$-manifolds without boundary. Otherwise, we don't have an intersection pairing on $H^{2k}(M)$.

Comment: Yes, but I think you need it to be closed. otherwise poincare duality won't give you a middle dimensional pairing.

Comment: Sorry, I will revise my question ...

Comment: If you show that $S^2\times D^2$ admits a Einstein metric, you can easily show your statement.

Comment: The signature can be thought of as the signature of the intersection form $H_2(M)\otimes H_2(M)\to \mathbb Z$. This may be the way it is defined for non-closed $4$-manifolds. In that case, it's easy to see that $H_2(M)$ is generated by $S^2\times \{0\}$, and this has trivial self-intersection since there is a parallel push-off which is disjoint, implying that the intersection form is identically $0$.

Comment: This is not a comment, it is an answer ... but could you please also explain what the homological intersection form is?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: you forgot to ping me! I just happened to glance back at this question. I posted my comment as an answer with some additional details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature can be thought of as the signature of the intersection form $H_2(M)\otimes H_2(M)\to\mathbb Z.$ This may be the way it is defined for non-closed 4-manifolds. In that case, it's easy to see that $H_2(M)$ is generated by $S^2×\{0\}$, and this has trivial self-intersection since there is a parallel push-off which is disjoint, implying that the intersection form is identically $0$.

The intersection form $H_2(M)\otimes H_2(M)\to \mathbb Z$ is defined by realizing $2$-dimensional homology classes as maps of surfaces into $M$. The algebraic intersection number between two surfaces is defined by first putting them in general position with respect to each other, and then counting their intersections with sign. Note that a surface in a $4$-manifold generically hits another surface in a finite collection of points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's (almost) clear to me now. Only one question is left, why does every homology class arise from an embedded surface?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1489/cohomology-and-fundamental-classes. I wasn't assuming that the surfaces are embedded, but you can assume that with no loss of generality.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Do you happen to know if this signature is related with the signature of a link defined using the linking number form on Seifert surfaces?